# Given the result of grep -n, how can I open vim in that specific line? (using only keyboard)

Tags: command-line, vim, grep

When I run `grep "keyword" -n` and get the following list of results:

```
a/b/c:10:    keyword
a/b/c:70:    keyword
a/b/d:50:    keyword
```

How can I open one of the files (say the 2nd in list) in the line it found?

I now just copy the the output using my mouse, and copy it after `vim` and then add `+` with the line number I copy. (meaning I write `vim a/b/c +70` using the mouse copy to get the file name, and another mouse copy to get the line number [or I just copy it by hand, when its short enough])

Is there a way to do it with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: You can try something like that: `echo a/b/c:70:    keyword | awk '{print $1}'  | sed 's,:$,,' | sed 's,:, +,' | xargs vim && reset`.

Comment: Also, if you're interested in using Vim more efficiently, do check out the dedicated [vi.se] Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two things:

1. Vim has some support for `grep`.

   If you open Vim, and do [`:grep keyword ...`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Agrep), Vim populates [the quickfix list](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix) with the results, and jumps to the first file. You can then jump to the *n*th quickfix entry with [`:cc n`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acc) (and other commands).
2. You can populate the aforementioned quickfix list using grep's output:

   ```
   vim -q <(grep -n keyword ...)
   ```

   And then use the quickfix navigation commands mentioned above.

Either is simpler than playing around with grep's output manually.

As an alternative to (2), you can save grep's output to a file and use that file instead, if you think you won't necessarily open Vim after:

```
grep ... | tee log
vim -q log
```

Comment: Trying to use the same method on git status, to no avail :( - vim -q <(git status | grep modified)

Comment: @CIsForCookies That won't be in the same format as `grep -n` (`<filename>:<line>: ...`). I use the [fugitive plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) for Git, and then it's a matter of `:Gstatus`, move to desired file and press Enter.

Comment: BTW, I edited my *~/.bashrc* `grep alias` to use colors always, and that, for some reason, broke the `-q >()` option...

Comment: @ClsForCookies you can disable the colors (even if they are set in the alias as you said) using `--colors=never` option. Taking @muru 's example, it would be something like: `vim -q <(grep --colors=never -n keyword ...)`

Answer (score 2):

You could make is so if there were not support for grep already as @muru answered:

```
:cexpr system("grep -n keyword")
```

It can be used with another command, `git grep` for example.

Also, you can open the output in a buffer and use "cbuffer" on it.

See [quickfix](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html) section from the manual about it.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output of `grep` to `vim` and use the [gF](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#gF) family of motions to move to the file under the cursor.

```
grep "keyword" -rn | vim -
```